# Fisheye-Equirectangular conversion

Tags: computer-vision, fisheye

I have an intrinsic parameter(fx,fy, cx,cy, k1~k4) of fisheye camera obtained by OpenCV's fisheye::calibrate(). How can I convert the fisheye image to an equirectangular image?

I have seen some similar questions but none of them seems to reflect the calibration results. Are distortion parameters k1~k4 not necessary in this conversion?

Comment: Are you using the Python bindings or C++?

Comment: currently using c++

Answer (score 0):

[This Medium article](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0), while in Python might offer some further reading on the topic. It seems to indicate that once you have obtained the K and D values from fisheye::calibrate you can then use [fisheye::initUndistortRectifyMap](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#ga0d37b45f780b32f63ed19c21aa9fd333) (note that D can be empty, as it seems to be in your case) to generate two Maps, which can then be used with [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) to transform the warped input image into a dewarped output image (further reading on remapping [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/da0/tutorial_remap.html)).

In python (for anyone looking at this later) this is done as such:

```
ap1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3),
                                                K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
undistorted_img = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2,
                            interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, 
                            borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to append a C++ sample, but I hope this helps put you on the right path.

Comment: I've referred to [this page](https://tenteroring.luna.ddns.vc/tenteroring/2017/04/1697) to obtain undistorted image and the steps include what you have suggested. But obviously this is not an equirectangular image.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misinterpreted your question.